# MySQL one file per table not working

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-8.0, tablespaces, ibdata

I've followed all of the instructions for enabling the one file per table in MySQL (v8, on Ubuntu 20):

- Added innodb_file_per_table=ON
- Restarted MySQL
- Dumped all databases, one by one.

However, when I import the databases back, everything is written to ibdata1 file.
But, When I create a brand new DB via MySQL Client, and add a random table to it, the data is written to its own folder + table.ibd file.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Few troubleshooting steps I tried:

- Reboot
- show variables like 'innodb_file_per_table';  (Value = ON)

Comment: *However, when I import the databases back, everything is written to ibdata1 file.* Have you deleted/recreated the database? or its tables at least? `innodb_file_per_table` setting is applied to newly created tables only and not affects on existing tables.

Comment: Yup.  I deleted the databases.  And then because of some mistakes, I had to purge mysql completely, then reinstall it.

Comment: If so then check the dump. Maybe it contains a statement which disables file per table?

Comment: How would one go about doing that?  Another thing I just noticed - some of the tables within the same DB were written into separate files.

Comment: *How would one go about doing that?* The dump is common (but large) text file. You may search for `innodb_file_per_table` in it using some text viewer/aditor which can work with large foles, or simply using `find` command-line utility

Comment: Which section of my.cnf did you put the statement in?  Did you "dump" using `mysqldump`?  Or something else?  What parameters were on that command?

Comment: @RickJames  I 'dumped' using mysqldump  & command.   No parameters ... just mysqldump -u  -p -h localhost databsaename | gzip > /a/b/c/databasename.sql.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [innodb_file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) is enabled by default for MySQL 8.

If you want to know what tables are sitting in ibdata1, run the following query

```
select * from information_schema.innodb_tables;
```

This will inform you about each table and what tablespace it resides in

### EXAMPLE

I spun of a vagrant lab that runs MySQL 8.0.17

I loaded the KJV of the Bible and added a fulltext index

Here is the output of the query I mentioned

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_tables;
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+------+--------+------------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME                                                | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE      | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE | INSTANT_COLS |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+------+--------+------------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|     1025 | mysql/db                                            |  161 |     25 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1026 | mysql/user                                          |  161 |     54 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1027 | mysql/default_roles                                 |  161 |      7 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1028 | mysql/role_edges                                    |  161 |      8 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1029 | mysql/global_grants                                 |  161 |      7 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1030 | mysql/password_history                              |  161 |      7 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1031 | mysql/func                                          |  161 |      7 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1032 | mysql/plugin                                        |  161 |      5 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1054 | mysql/help_topic                                    |  161 |      9 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1055 | mysql/help_category                                 |  161 |      7 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1057 | mysql/help_relation                                 |  161 |      5 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1036 | mysql/servers                                       |  161 |     12 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1037 | mysql/tables_priv                                   |  161 |     11 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1038 | mysql/columns_priv                                  |  161 |     10 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1056 | mysql/help_keyword                                  |  161 |      5 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1040 | mysql/time_zone_name                                |  161 |      5 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1041 | mysql/time_zone                                     |  161 |      5 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1042 | mysql/time_zone_transition                          |  161 |      6 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1043 | mysql/time_zone_transition_type                     |  161 |      8 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1044 | mysql/time_zone_leap_second                         |  161 |      5 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1045 | mysql/procs_priv                                    |  161 |     11 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1046 | mysql/component                                     |  161 |      6 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1047 | mysql/slave_relay_log_info                          |  161 |     12 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1048 | mysql/slave_master_info                             |  161 |     31 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1049 | mysql/slave_worker_info                             |  161 |     16 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1050 | mysql/gtid_executed                                 |  161 |      6 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1051 | mysql/server_cost                                   |  161 |      7 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1052 | mysql/engine_cost                                   |  161 |      9 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1053 | mysql/proxies_priv                                  |  161 |     10 | 4294967294 | Dynamic    |             0 | General    |            0 |
|     1058 | sys/sys_config                                      |   33 |      7 |          1 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1101 | bible/verses                                        |   33 |      8 |         44 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1102 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_being_deleted            |   33 |      4 |         45 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1103 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_being_deleted_cache      |   33 |      4 |         46 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1104 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_config                   |   33 |      5 |         47 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1105 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_deleted                  |   33 |      4 |         48 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1106 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_deleted_cache            |   33 |      4 |         49 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1107 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_00000000000000cd_index_1 |   33 |      8 |         50 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1108 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_00000000000000cd_index_2 |   33 |      8 |         51 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1109 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_00000000000000cd_index_3 |   33 |      8 |         52 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1110 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_00000000000000cd_index_4 |   33 |      8 |         53 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1111 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_00000000000000cd_index_5 |   33 |      8 |         54 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1112 | bible/fts_000000000000044d_00000000000000cd_index_6 |   33 |      8 |         55 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1113 | bible/books                                         |   33 |      5 |         56 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1150 | ft_db/ft_test_innodb                                |   33 |      6 |         93 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1151 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_being_deleted            |   33 |      4 |         94 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1152 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_being_deleted_cache      |   33 |      4 |         95 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1153 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_config                   |   33 |      5 |         96 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1154 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_deleted                  |   33 |      4 |         97 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1155 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_deleted_cache            |   33 |      4 |         98 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1156 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_0000000000000107_index_1 |   33 |      8 |         99 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1157 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_0000000000000107_index_2 |   33 |      8 |        100 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1158 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_0000000000000107_index_3 |   33 |      8 |        101 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1159 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_0000000000000107_index_4 |   33 |      8 |        102 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1160 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_0000000000000107_index_5 |   33 |      8 |        103 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
|     1161 | ft_db/fts_000000000000047e_0000000000000107_index_6 |   33 |      8 |        104 | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |            0 |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+------+--------+------------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
55 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc information_schema.innodb_tables;
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TABLE_ID      | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     |         |       |
| NAME          | varchar(655)        | NO   |     |         |       |
| FLAG          | int(11)             | NO   |     |         |       |
| N_COLS        | int(11)             | NO   |     |         |       |
| SPACE         | bigint(21)          | NO   |     |         |       |
| ROW_FORMAT    | varchar(12)         | YES  |     |         |       |
| ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | int(11) unsigned    | NO   |     |         |       |
| SPACE_TYPE    | varchar(10)         | YES  |     |         |       |
| INSTANT_COLS  | int(11)             | NO   |     |         |       |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Please note that any table whose `space` value is 0, resides in the `ibdata1`. It says to in the [MySQL 8.0 Docs about INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-innodb-tables-table.html);

At the moment, there are no tables in `ibdata1`.

Let's see If I can inject one into `ibdata1`.

```
mysql> use bible
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql>
mysql>
mysql> set global innodb_file_per_table = 'OFF';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table injection (id int not null auto_increment, name varchar(20), primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into injection (name) values ('Hello, World !!!');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from injection;
+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | Hello, World !!! |
+----+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK, now let's check information_schema

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_tables where space = 0;
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME            | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE | INSTANT_COLS |
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|     1162 | bible/injection |   33 |      5 |     0 | Dynamic    |             0 | System     |            0 |
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

### TADA !!!

OK, so now go run

```
select * from information_schema.innodb_tables where space = 0;
```

If you don't see any rows returned, then you have nothing in `ibdata1`.

### WHAT IF I STILL HAVE TABLES IN `ibdata1`?

If you are starting brand new in MySQL. You should not have this problem from the beginning. Notwithstanding, let's say you have this situation in MySQL 8.0. How to you do yank the table out of `ibdata1` ???

#### Let's try `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB`

Unfortunately, you cannot perform a NULL ALTER like before:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_tables where space = 0;
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME            | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE | INSTANT_COLS |
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|     1162 | bible/injection |   33 |      5 |     0 | Dynamic    |             0 | System     |            0 |
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global innodb_file_per_table = 'ON';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table bible.injection engine=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_tables where space = 0;
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME            | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE | INSTANT_COLS |
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|     1163 | bible/injection |  161 |      5 |     0 | Dynamic    |             0 | System     |            0 |
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

[You could get away with this in MySQL 5.7 and back](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24942/how-do-i-shrink-the-innodb-file-ibdata1-without-dumping-all-databases/24963#24963). For MySQL 8.0, the temp table used maintains the table's current tablespace metadata.

### Let's try `CREATE TABLE LIKE`

```
mysql> create table bible.injection2 like bible.injection;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_tables where space = 0;
+----------+------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME             | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE | INSTANT_COLS |
+----------+------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|     1163 | bible/injection  |  161 |      5 |     0 | Dynamic    |             0 | System     |            0 |
|     1164 | bible/injection2 |  161 |      5 |     0 | Dynamic    |             0 | System     |            0 |
+----------+------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@global.innodb_file_per_table;
+--------------------------------+
| @@global.innodb_file_per_table |
+--------------------------------+
|                              1 |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK Ouch !!!. That pesky tablespace metadata gets dragged around like luggage.

### Let's try `ALTER TABLE ... TABLESPACE=innodb_file_per_table`

Here we go ...

```
mysql> create table bible.injection2 like bible.injection;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_tables where space = 0;
+----------+------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME             | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE | INSTANT_COLS |
+----------+------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|     1163 | bible/injection  |  161 |      5 |     0 | Dynamic    |             0 | System     |            0 |
|     1164 | bible/injection2 |  161 |      5 |     0 | Dynamic    |             0 | System     |            0 |
+----------+------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@global.innodb_file_per_table;
+--------------------------------+
| @@global.innodb_file_per_table |
+--------------------------------+
|                              1 |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE bible.injection2 TABLESPACE=innodb_file_per_table;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_tables where space = 0;
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME            | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE | INSTANT_COLS |
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|     1163 | bible/injection |  161 |      5 |     0 | Dynamic    |             0 | System     |            0 |
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE bible.injection TABLESPACE=innodb_file_per_table;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_tables where space = 0;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

### TADA !!!

## CONCLUSION

If you suspect any tables are in `ibdata1`, find them with

```
select * from information_schema.innodb_tables where space = 0;
```

Then just run

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable TABLESPACE=innodb_file_per_table;
```

Please remember: The default [innodb_file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) is `ON`.

No need to mysqldump and reload.

If you are attempting to shrink ibdata1, you will have load data into a brand new installation. [You cannot just delete ibdata1 like you could in MySQL 5.5 and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261). MySQL 5.6 + has innodb tables in the `mysql` schema database. So, you cannot play the same file manipulation games. MySQL 8.0 now demands a lot more respect from a DBA.

Comment: Thank you, trying this out now, hopefully that will do the trick.  That said, if I wanted to carry over database from server 1, that does not have filer per table enabled, to server 2, and have tables in one file per table - is there a way to do that via mysqldump (server 1 & 2 are mysql 8)?  The method i tried originally, did not convert the tables to file per table.

Comment: You did not specify `--add-drop-table` when launching the mysqldump. It probably has `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in the dump now. You will have to drop the tables in the place you are trying to load it. Try recreating the dump with `--add-drop-table`. When the script does the `DROP TABLE` command, the metadata will disappear with it. So, ibdata1 should no longer know about the table's prior existence.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  If i run into this again, I will re-create the mysqldump with this option.  But for the time being, your original ALTER TABLE suggestion worked.  Bummer ibdata file can not be deleted in mysql 8, but that is something I can live with until next upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

For simply finding out where a table is:

Versions 5.6, 5.7, most of MariaDB:

I created two tables in database `ftp`:

```
mysql>     SELECT  name, space
    ->         FROM  information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLES
    ->         WHERE  name LIKE 'fpt/%';
+-------------+-------+
| name        | space |
+-------------+-------+
| fpt/in_fpt  |   491 |  -- non-zero implies innodb_file_per_table = ON
| fpt/not_fpt |     0 |  -- implies OFF (that is, in ibdata1)
+-------------+-------+
```

In MySQL 8.0, use this table:  `information_schema.INNODB_TABLESPACES`, but a non-file-per-table table is indicated by absence from the table, not `0`.