# Why was default of innodb_file_per_table changed?

Tags: mysql

Is there a disadvantage in using `file per table storage`? I wonder why the default of the value `innodb_file_per_table` was changed with **MySQL 5.7**.

Documentation shows that the default value changed (`to "OFF"`), so there must be a reason:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table

Reference: [Is innodb_file_per_table advisable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/is-innodb-file-per-table-advisable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value has been `ON`, [since 5.6.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table).

You're looking at the 5.5 documentation, which only refers to the defaults in 5.5 -- not 5.7.  In version 5.5.7, a decision was made to revert the defaults to match 5.1 in an effort to avoid a replication incompatibility.

> the default values for `innodb_file_per_table` and `innodb_file_format` are reverted to the MySQL 5.1 default values—that is, OFF and Antelope, respectively. (Bug #56318, Bug #11763590)
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-7.html

In 5.6.6 (before 5.6 GA) the default value changed back to `ON`.

> The motivation for these changes is to provide better out-of-box performance and to reduce the need for database administrators to change settings manually.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-6.html

In [5.7, the default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) is still `ON`.