# How To Optimize and Repair InnoDB tables? ALTER and OPTIMIZE table failed

Tags: mysql, innodb

I just switched my Wordpress databases to use the InnoDB engine.

When using MyISAM, I used to run `Optimize` and `Repair table`. However, with InnoDB, these don't work.

I manually ran `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and the suggested `ALTER TABLE` but none of them removed the overhead. I ran `mysqltuner` on my server which showed 14 fragmented tables - I have a total of 14 tables.  Even after running `optimize` and `alter tables`, all 14 tables are still fragmented!

How can I properly `OPTIMIZE` and `REPAIR` InnoDB tables?

Comment: Is the fragmentation causing problems? How big are the tables we are talking about?

Comment: Please run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';` and tell me, is it enabled or disabled ???

Comment: @ypercube No I can't see any problems in the site... The sql dump of the database is 32MB (A small database)

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA innodb_file_per_table | OFF

Comment: With such a tiny database, I don't think you should worry at all. Rolando should comment really, on when and if you should run `OPTIMIZE` and `REPAIR` on InnoDB tables (or provide links to his previous answers).

Comment: @ypercube ok :) I'll wait for his comment.. I hsve file per table off.. is it ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ouch you have innodb_file_per_table off

I wrote articles on this before. You will have to convert the InnoDB infrastructure.

- `Oct 29, 2010` : [My Original Post in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)
- `Apr 01, 2012` : [Is innodb_file_per_table advisable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/is-innodb-file-per-table-advisable/15907#15907)
- `Mar 25, 2012` : [Why does InnoDB store all databases in one file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file/15542#15542)
- `Feb 03, 2012` : [Scheduled optimization of tables in MySQL InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/scheduled-optimization-of-tables-in-mysql-innodb/12205#12205)
- `Nov 26, 2011` : [ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/error-1114-hy000-at-line-6308-in-file-the-table-user-analysis-is-full/8412#8412)

Once you do this, anytime you do OPTIMIZE TABLE to an InnoDB, it will actually shrink.

If you do not perform the InnoDB infrastructure cleanup, the ibdata1 file will actually grow in size. To make matter worse, I think mysqltuner.pl is using a weird algorithm for determining InnoDB fragmentation. I tend to ignore it.

I check for fragmentation differently.

Back on April 19, 2012 I answered a question similar to this: [How do you remove fragmentation from InnoDB tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/how-do-you-remove-fragmentation-from-innodb-tables/16353#16353).

Here is what I said in that earlier post:

> After running the above steps, how can you determine what tables need
>   to be defragmentated? It is possible to find out, but you will have
>   script it.
>
> Here is an example: Suppose you have the table `mydb.mytable`. With
>   innodb_file_per_table enabled, you have the file
>   /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd
>
> You will have to retrieve two numbers
>
> FILESIZE FROM OS : You can ascertain the filesize from the OS like
>   this
>
> ```
> ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd | awk '{print $5}'
> ```
>
> FILESIZE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA : You can ascertain the filesize from
>   information_schema.tables like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT (data_length+index_length) tblsize FROM information_schema.tables
> WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';
> ```
>
> Just subtract INFORMATION_SCHEMA value from OS value and divide the
>   difference by the INFORMATION_SCHEMA value.

From there you would decide what percentage deems it necessary to defrag that table. In other words, if there is a big difference between the filesize of the `.ibd` file and the number from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, go ahead with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`. Regardless of the filesize, please don't worry if the fragmentation is less than 1%.

Comment: Do I have to drop even the performance_schema and the mysql databases?

Comment: You do not have to drop performance_schema and the mysql databases. In fact, please do not touch the mysql schema.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot... Im going to clean it now :)

Comment: Performed the cleanup and it did a big change :) But still, mysqltuner show 5 more fragmented tables. How to check this?

Comment: Updated my answer...

Comment: The first table I tested have 1.89% fragmentation. But OPTIMIZE TABLE won't reduce it

Comment: What is the name of that table and what database is it in ???

Comment: wp_commentmeta ... The 5 tables with fragmentation are : wp_commentmeta wp_comments wp_options wp_postmeta and wp_posts  (Its a wordpress site)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4650/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-eapubs)