# Database space doesn't match ibdata1 size

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm using InnoDB database with a single file configuration (in /var), so no innodb_file_per_table.

In the MySql workbench, when I query for the databases used space, with this query

```
SELECT table_schema "Database", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data     Base Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
```

I get 47 GB.
However, when I check the space on the /var directory with df -h, it returns 129 GB of used space. Last week, this was at 127 GB, so I know that the whole 129 GB is used because new space is allocated by MySql.

I was under the impression that when deleting rows from a table, the space was freed, but the ibdata1 does not skrink and re-use the space latter.

So my question is, why does ibdata1 keep growing to 129 GB and beyond when, supposedly, my databases only uses 47 GB of space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a lot like another post I wrote back on August 27, 2012 : [How To Optimize and Repair InnoDB tables? ALTER and OPTIMIZE table failed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23206/how-to-optimize-and-repair-innodb-tables-alter-and-optimize-table-failed/23211#23211)

With [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled, the system tablespace `ibdata1` is the home of seven classes of information:

- Data Pages for InnoDB Tables
- Index Pages for InnoDB Tables
- Data Dictionary
- Double Write Buffer

  - Safety Net to Prevent Data Corruption
  - Helps Bypass OS for Caching
- Insert Buffer (Streamlines Changes to Secondary Indexes)
- Rollback Segments
- Undo Logs
- [Click Here to see a Pictorial Representation of `ibdata1`](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)

With [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled, running [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) against any InnoDB table is *really asking for trouble*. Why? Because all [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) does is write all data pages and index pages for a given table contiguously in `ibdata1`. That makes `ibdata1` grow. In light of this, shrinkage of `ibdata1` is totally impossible.

Please note that even if [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) were enabled and you ran [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html), that will extract the table into an external file. Yet, the space left behind is unrecoverable.

I wrote a nice [**one-time Cleanup Procedure of ibdata1 in StackOverflow back on Oct 29, 2010**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261).

Here are my other posts on this subject of InnoDB and its effects on ibdata1

- `Apr 01, 2012` : [Is innodb_file_per_table advisable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/is-innodb-file-per-table-advisable/15907#15907)
- `Mar 25, 2012` : [Why does InnoDB store all databases in one file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file/15542#15542)
- `Feb 03, 2012` : [Scheduled optimization of tables in MySQL InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/scheduled-optimization-of-tables-in-mysql-innodb/12205#12205)
- `Nov 26, 2011` : [ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/error-1114-hy000-at-line-6308-in-file-the-table-user-analysis-is-full/8412#8412)

## SUMMARY

Even if you implement the [InnoDB Cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261) (which separates all data and index pages from `ibdata1`), `ibdata1` can still grow in a heavy-write, heavy transaction environment due to the 5 other classes of information (Data Dictionary, Double Write Buffer, Insert Buffer, Rollback Segments, Undo Logs).

If you want to know how much space is used by data and index pages in ibdata1, run this:

```
SELECT InnoDB_Bytes,InnoDB_Bytes/POWER(1024,3) InnoDB_GB
FROM (SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) InnoDB_Bytes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;
```

Now as for ibdata1, it still the Data Dictionary, Double Write Buffer, Insert Buffer, Rollback Segments, Undo Logs, and unused pages due to fragmentation. There is no really way to know:

- the exact amount of fragmentation
- how much space is used by the following (since they change rapidly):

  - Data Dictionary
  - Double Write Buffer
  - Insert Buffer
  - Rollback Segments
  - Undo Logs

For the sake of simplicity, I will say this: Just subtract `InnoDB_Bytes` from the filesize of ibdata1.

After doing the [InnoDB Cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261), you should schedule running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on every InnoDB table that is transaction-heavy. That will actually shrink the `.ibd` file for every InnoDB tables. The `ibdata1` file will grow much slower thereafter. Yet, you will still have to live with some transactional growth.

If you implement [InnoDB Cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261) but leave [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled, that will shrink shrink `ibdata1`, but it will just climb back to 99G and beyond through normal application usage.

If you do not implement [InnoDB Cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261), no [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) will ever shrink `ibdata1`.

## RECOMMENDATION

Please implement [InnoDB Cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261) with [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled. Going forward, you should create a cronjob to run [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) on all tables what experience mass INSERTs, mass UPDATEs, and mass DELETEs.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer.
I ran your sql command and I get 47 GB, which is consistent with what I had found. That means that I have 47 GB of actual data in a ibdata1 file of 99 GB.

Is this normal?
I often delete millions of rows from different table to clean up space. Can this be a problem?
Also, my database is used in a write-heavy environment (several hundreds of write per second).

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, if I do the 'InnoDB Cleanup' with `innodb_file_per_table` enabled, would I still have lots of huge files starting like 'FTS_\*.ibd' in my database folder? I have about 240Gb data but the folder has the size of about 400Gb due to these 'FTS_*.ibd' files

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, DELETE order doesn't release space... You should reorganize tables with **OPTIMIZE TABLE** order.

If you can stop activity, you can also make a dump and **restore it**.

Max.

Comment: One of the disadvantage to not use innodb_file_per_table is the difficulty to identify what database are problematics...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But deleted space, even if the ibdata1 file doesn't skrink should be reused. What I don't get is why my mysql/var partition keeps growing when I supposedly only have 47 GB worth of data.

Comment: Try the following request, it detects table which freespaces that can be removed with OPTIMIZE TABLE order : SELECT s.schema_name, table_name,
IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(data_free)/1024,2),0.00) data_free
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA s, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
WHERE s.schema_name = t.table_schema
GROUP BY s.schema_name, table_name
HAVING data_free > 100
ORDER BY data_free DESC