# Removing/overwriting sensitive data located in already deleted records in ibdata files

Tags: mysql, innodb, ibdata

As far as I know, using InnoDB tables with `innodb_file_per_table = off` does not prevent deleted data from being visible in the `ibdata1` file.

I know this is by-design, and that I could switch the system setup to use `innodb_file_per_table = on`, which would allow the system to shred the `ibdata*` files containing the sensitive information, however there is "no server downtime allowed"

Could I simply overwrite the sensitive information in the `ibdata1` file somehow, so that some erroneous `this is sensitive` reads `this is xxxxxxxxx` afterwards.

I'm not a DBA and neither know whether this would work out at all, or will destroy some checksums, crash the server, or whatever.

So my question is, what can I do to prevent leaking in the meantime without affecting the stability of the running server?

Comment: I think your only way is to avoid ibdata1 from being accessed by anyone apart from mysql processes.  This you can achieve on filesystem level without restarting MySQL (but still have to be careful not to harm your system).

Comment: Or, probably, you can devise a solution based on `OPTIMIZE TABLE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: @dezso - access to `var/lib/mysql` already was/is restricted to the `mysql` user.

Comment: Then how do you expect ibdata contents leaking?

Comment: @dezso - Doesn't `OPTIMIZE TABLE` lock the table for the time optimizing? Because if so, then it unfortunately will not help.

Comment: @dezso - maybe I'm just overly paranoid, but we just want to minimize as much risk as we can.

Answer (score 2):

Switching to [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) is not enough because ibdata1 would still be the same size.

Any tables that were inside ibdatat1 and you ran OPTIMIZE TABLE against, it would simply manifest the table and its indexes to a `.ibd` file. You would still have the footprint of the table inside ibdata1. You are much better off restructuring InnoDB so that no data and index pages reside in ibdata1

Think about it: With innodb_file_per_table off, what goes inside ibdata1 besides data and indexes?

- Data dictionary
- Double Write Buffer (Background write to prevent reliance on OS caching)
- Insert Buffer (Managing changes to non-unique secondary indexes)
- Rollback Segments
- Undo Space
- [**Pictorial Representation**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)

Some of these may eventually overwrite old data and index pages, but how long is eventually? Would it not be better to completely compress ibdata1? Basically, it would entail:

- doing a mysqldump of all databases
- deleting ibdata1
- making sure innodb_data_file_path is the default (ibdata1:10M:autoextend) in /etc/my.cnf
- starting up mysqld to let it recreate ibdata1
- reloading the mysqldump.

Please see my past links on how to do so...

- `Oct 29, 2010` : [**My Original Post in StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)
- `Apr 01, 2012` : [Is innodb_file_per_table advisable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/is-innodb-file-per-table-advisable/15907#15907)
- `Mar 25, 2012` : [Why does InnoDB store all databases in one file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file/15542#15542)
- `Feb 03, 2012` : [Scheduled optimization of tables in MySQL InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/scheduled-optimization-of-tables-in-mysql-innodb/12205#12205)
- `Nov 26, 2011` : [ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/error-1114-hy000-at-line-6308-in-file-the-table-user-analysis-is-full/8412#8412)

Comment: I _will_ go the `innodb_file_per_table = on` way, that's for sure. Not sure though,  what "completely compress ibdata1" does mean exactly in this context, but I'll definitely gonna check your links, thank you. Still, my main problem is another one: what to do until I even get the chance to change the InnoDB setup? Like mentioned, we won't get any time slot the next few days, where we could change the server setup. What to do to prevent leaking in the meantime?