# InnoDB insertion faster

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, insert

I'm a graduate school student researching OLAP with Mondrian OLAP. So I want to insert data into InnoDB (MySQL 5.5) faster at the initial loading. In this environment, the only user is me, so I think can allow more loose settings for insertion speed. At the moment, I'm using the following techniques.

- disable `log_bin`
- enable `skip-innodb-doublewrite`
- set `transaction_isolation` to `READ-COMMITTED` or `READ-UNCOMMITTED` (actually `READ-COMMITED`)
- set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to `0` or `2` (actually `0`)
- set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 5GB (system has 6GB RAM)

Are there any more techniques for faster insertion on InnoDB?
And do I have to modify `innodb_io_read_thread` and `innodb_io_write_thread` ?
If you need more information, please tell me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## SUGGESTION #1

If your machine has multiple cores, you need to increase the following:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_io_capacity = 5000
```

What are these?

- [innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) - The number of I/O threads for read operations in InnoDB.
- [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) - The number of I/O threads for write operations in InnoDB.
- [innodb_io_capacity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_io_capacity) - An upper limit on the I/O activity performed by the InnoDB background tasks, such as flushing pages from the buffer pool and merging data from the insert buffer.

## SUGGESTION #2

In order for separate data and indexes from the system tablespace (ibdata1), you need to do perform a complete restructuring of InnoDB. Sounds complicated, but is very straightforward. I wrote about this in the [**DBA StackExchange** (Aug 29, 2012)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23367/877) and in [**StackOverflow** (Oct 29, 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056261/491757). The basic steps are

- Run `SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;`
- mysqldump all data to a SQL dump
- `service mysql stop`
- Delete the following files

  - `ibdata1`
  - `ib_logfile0`
  - `ib_logfile1`
- `service mysql start`

Before you run `service mysql start`, add this line to `my.cnf`

```
innodb_open_files=32768
```

That way, there will be file handles dedicated to the each individual table. The default is 300. [**File handles have been known to get cached. There will be a slowdown if you set this  very high and hit the ceiling quickly**](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/11/18/how-innodb_open_files-affects-performance/). This should not be the case if you are working a small number of tables.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll try suggestion #2 right now, and I'll adjust `innodb_read_io_threads`, `innodb_write_io_threads`, and `innodb_io_capacity'.

Comment: "Delete the following files ibdata1"

Sheesh, without a warning.

Answer (score 6):

There's an entire [document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) dedicated to bulk loading data into InnoDB. The main points:

1. disable autocommit to avoid an extra log flush for each insert statement: `SET autocommit=0;...sql import;COMMIT;`
2. disable foreign and unique checks (you can't disable all indexes completely):

   ```
   SET unique_checks=0;
   SET foreign_key_checks=0;
   ```
3. Potentially set [innodb_autoinc_lock_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode) to 2, instead of 1 (the default). [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-configurable) is the documentation on this setting.

The third may or may not help you, so I suggest reading that link to see how you are initially loading the data. For instance, if you are breaking the loads into multiple inserts to run concurrently, it will definitely help you to set the value to 2. If you are doing one large multi-line insert, it won't do much (if anything) to help.

Since you are turning of the binary log for this initial insert, you shouldn't care about the gaps in autoincrement numbers (if doing concurrent inserts).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Bulk insert looks so fast, and I'll try it later.

Comment: Just  setting autocommit=0 increased though-put by orders of magnitude. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following methods to speed up inserts:

- If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time, use `INSERT` statements with multiple `VALUES` lists to insert several rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some cases) than using separate single-row `INSERT` statements. If you are adding data to a nonempty table, you can tune the bulk_insert_buffer_size variable to make data insertion even faster.
- When loading a table from a text file, use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. This is usually 20 times faster than using `INSERT` statements. [See](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
- Take advantage of the fact that columns have default values. Insert values explicitly only when the value to be inserted differs from the default. This reduces the parsing that MySQL must do and improves the insert speed.
- See Section 9.5.5, “[Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)” for tips specific to InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  "Batch" INSERTs -- multiple rows per INSERT statement.  Suggest about 1000 rows per statement.  autocommit=on, no explicit BEGIN...COMMIT

Plan B:  LOAD DATA

If you insert too many rows at once, InnoDB must do more work to be able to rollback the insert if there is a crash.  For this reason, I disagree with autocommit=off, which would put the entire set into a single transaction.

LOAD DATA of the entire set of rows may would have the same problem, but it is quite fast.

buffer_pool = 5G out of 6G is on the verge of being too big.  If there is any swapping, performance will plummet.

PARTITIONing would probably make it go slower.

SHOW CREATE TABLE -- Secondary keys could be a serious handicap.

Are you using InnoDB?  or XtraDB?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using InnoDB.
I prefer Plan A to Plan B. `LOAD DATA` look like so fast, but we need to write data to text at once as CSV, then use `LOAD DATA` right? / I'll set the `buffer_pool_size` to 4GB.