# What is limiting MySQL to write max. 10 Inserts per second?

Tags: mysql

I am running an MySQL server. Build a small RAID with 3 harddisks which can Write 300MB/s and this damn MySQL just don't want to speed up the writing. 10 Inserts per second is the max I have seen till now.

What is the bottleneck?!

Here are some Screenshots:

[image: MySQL Workbench Dashboard]

[image: htop during insert process]

Answers to comments:

- Example table: 10 Double Columns and one Datetime, 500.000 rows (to import)
- The inserts I do are just initial data inputs like 500.000 times "insert into ... value ..."
- I tried RazorSQL which is sending 500 transactions at once, but no effect.
- It is a RAID0 with 3x2TB no-SSD-disks.

Tuning LOG:

- SET GLOBAL sync_binlog = 500; results in 20.25 inserts per second.
- SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2684354560; no effect
- SET innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4 (in mysqld.conf); setup in config file makes no effect. still instances = 1.

Comment: What do the tables look like? What sort of database is it? What are the inserts? How much data is there?

Comment: This is not a programming question, this is a question either for a DBA or a system administrator.

Comment: Is there a bottleneck ? Is the statistics here from where you did a performance test - or is it just the normal operation of your database ? Do you actually try to insert an average of more than 12 rows every second averaged over the day ?  In any case, make sure you do bulk inserts (insert many rows at a time) within a transaction, instead if wrapping a single insert into a single transaction if you need more performance.

Comment: Which RAID setup? And is the RAID hardware or software controlled.

Comment: Do you have a bad disk in your RAID0 set up? One bad apple spoils the bunch here. I wonder, too, if you are dealing with mysql blocks being split across your RAID0 disks. I haven't ever dealt with that, but if your RAID0 stripe array and block size is smaller than your innodb blocks, I would imagine that would cause quite a mess (totally guessing here since I've never dealt with such a problem).

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statement (including the indices) of your table and the complete `INSERT INTO` statement you try to run to your question.

Comment: RazorSQL seems to be a client end software like Toad.  Please post a small sample of your `INSERT` script.

Comment: How are you doing the inserts?  `LOAD DATA` (best)?  Multi-row `INSERT` (also good)?  Or one row at a time, each being effectively a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is my SOLUTION. Imported my data of **500.000 rows in 3 minutes**. In fact a lot of this settings is not for company grade systems. In a private LAN with 1-2 workstations it should be okay.

Here is my config file for the record. May it help somebody and my future me. =)

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /raiddrive/mysql
log-error       = /raiddrive/mysql/error.log
bind-address    = 192.168.2.104
port            = 3306
#hardcore performance https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29913/innodb-insertion-faster
skip-log-bin
skip-innodb-doublewrite
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
#if you lost root password
#init-file      = /raiddrive/mysql/setroot.sql
secure_file_priv= ""
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8388608000
```

Comment: This is probably the main fix: `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0`